# Migration SVN -> GIT doubts

Tags: git, svn, migration

We consider to migrate from SVN to GIT in our company. I'm doing research about advantages and disadvantages. I have a list of advantages of git and some advantages of SVN. I found website https://svnvsgit.com/ where the defects of the GIT are prevalent. Can you tell me is this website right? I try to understand is GIT really good solution or does it have just a good marketing?

Comment: This is an opinion-based question. Some people prefer SVN, some prefer GIT. There's no objective answer. So this question is off-topic.

Comment: Having said that, I've never met anyone who has used both SVN and GIT, and preferred SVN.  And the industry consensus seems to be that GIT is far superior, as that's the direction practically everyone is moving.

Comment: So where should I add this question to not be off-topic? I chose 'Other' category because I didn't know where to ask and yes... I ask about others opinion.

Comment: Just because something is off-topic here doesn't mean it is on-topic elsewhere.

Comment: I just started reading through that svnvsgit.com list... Is that a comedy piece? It's so full of nonsense....

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what Flimzy says in his comment, Subversion vs Git comparisons, though sometimes very well documented, often tend to be biased, in one way or the other.

Don't migrate for the sake of migrating.

In the case you're mentioning, i.e. migrating your svn codebase to git repository(ies), a few questions arise :

**How are people at your company comfortable with either svn or git?**

You asking how good Git is suggests that you aren't a Git user. You haven't felt the need or haven't been required to work with it, and that's fine as it is.

IMHO, for several reasons I won't expose here (because they are exposed everywhere), Git is great. I tried it many years ago and I have loved using it since day 1. Whenever possible, I avoid using svn (and when I have to, I use *git svn*). But you shouldn't care.

What you should do is give it a try. Start the most basic "hello world" application. [Set up a git repository](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init). Read a tutorial, create a branch, rebase it, merge it back the master, do something stupid and break your working copy, restore it with a *git reflog* and so on.

Then if your crew is convinced that they must go for Git...

**Are you satisfied with your current continous integration/delivery/deployment workflow** (if you have one)?

A version control system is one thing, but nowadays this is just a cog in your continuous workflow:

- [source management](https://about.gitlab.com/)
- [code quality](https://www.sonarqube.org/)
- [build automation](https://jenkins.io/)
- [containerization](https://www.docker.com/)
- [repository management](https://www.sonatype.com/nexus-repository-sonatype)
- [configuration management](https://www.chef.io/)

This is probably what your company should aim for, step by step, and svn vs git is just the beginning of it. The rest is equally tricky and painful, everybody will have their perfect solution, that of course won't suit your need.

So, in a nutshell: try for yourself and good luck :)